# C , Pointers to structure in functions formatting

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm a beginner programmer and wish to ask how to properly use a pointer to a structure in a function (in this case `getRectangleDimension()` ).

I have attempted this question for a couple of hours and search this site an found nothing useful. Any help is appreciated!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define  UNKNOWN  -1
struct  rectangle
{
    int width;
    int length;
    int area;
};

void  getRectangleDimension(struct  rectangle* B)
{
    printf("what  is  the  width?\n");
    scanf("%d",  &B.width);
    printf("what  is  the  length?\n");
    scanf("%d",  &B.length);
}

int main()
{
    struct  rectangle  myBox;
    myBox.width=UNKNOWN;
    myBox.length=UNKNOWN;
    myBox.area=UNKNOWN;
    getRectangleDimension(&myBox);
    printRectangle(myBox);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `getRectangleDimension `, the `&B.width` should be `&B->width`. Rinse, Repeat for `length`.

Comment: this is not a simple typo, its a genuine confusion over levels of indirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer has to be dereferenced. One does this with the `*` operator. This is a very common operation and the C language uses `B->width` as a stand-in for `(*B).width`, which one should defiantly use. The `scanf` requires a pointer, `&B->width`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful

Comment: Only on Stack Overflow do you find things like `(*B).width`; everywhere else, you only see `B->width`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void  getRectangleDimension(struct  rectangle* B)
{
...
    scanf("%d",  &B.width);
```

needs to be

```
void  getRectangleDimension(struct  rectangle* B)
{
...
    scanf("%d",  &(B->width));
```

Why? B is a pointer to your struct. So `B->width` is the width member of the passed struct. `scanf` needs a pointer to the number to scan. So you need `&(B->width)`

I would not do `&B->width` because I can never remember the precedence of & and -> So not sure if that means `(&B)->width` or `&(B->width)`

Also as a general style note, dont use capital letters for variable or arg names. Caps are generally used for types, and constants. 'B' as a variable name causes a minor speed bump for most C readers

Comment: The parentheses around `B->width` in `&(B->width)` are unnecessary and unorthodox.  The dot `.` and arrow `->` operators have higher precedence than operations such as `&`, or (unary, dereferencing) `*` or `[…]` subscripting.